# Locking an IP to a computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, mysql

I have a network with 4 computers. Three are connected by cables to the WIFI Router, one connects by wifi

I have a static IP from my provider

The problem I have is that every time the router is rebooted it assigns new IP's to each computer. On three of them it's not a problem but it's a big problem on the fourth because I has to allow external access to a mysql database

In the router I locked the router assigned IP to that computer in Forwarding

But of course, everything screws up when the router is rebooted and it assigns new internal IPs

How can I lock the network IP on that specific computer so it doesn't change every reboot?

It would be nice if all 4 were locked, but the one urgently has to be locked

Comment: you do this by configuring address reservations in the router's DHCP server. that way the DHCP server knows to always give a specific IP to a specific box.

Comment: I have a Netis router. It doesn't have anything called DHCP server in the settings
Maybe "Static Routing Rule Settings"?

Comment: nope. static routes are a different kind of thing. Never heard of Netis.

Comment: I think I just found it: DHCP Server & DHCP Client List?

Comment: The DHCP Client List gives the ID, IP Address, MAC Address, Host Name, Reserved (all set to NO), status, and Operation. So, Can I just change "reserved" for that computer to "YES"?

Comment: I believe that that is the case. Sorry I'm not familliar with the interface for your router, but what you describe sounds exactly like what you are looking for. its saying "always give the nic with this MAC this IP".

Answer (score 1):

Hi Frank FIleccia,

Thanks for your question. Thanks for Frank Thomas’s answer too.

It’s very nice to hear that your problem has been solved.

I have another method to solve this issue.

Therefore, I post my answer and hope it can help others in this community.

To lock an IP to a computer in a router environment. We have two solutions.

Solution1: **Through router administrative**

This solution has been proposed by Frank Thomas, I re-organize and refine it in my answer.

1.Login to router administrative(routers in different brands have different ways to login)
[image]

2.Found  DHCP and do some settings in address reservation.
You can set specific IP address for specific computer according to the computer adapter’s MAC address, An specific IP has been locked to a computer now, you need to reboot your router to enable the setting.
Here is a link about how to open command prompt and get MAC address. 
https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=4273

[image]

Solution2: **Through adapter administrative**

In this solution, you don’t need to set router, just need to set your adapter properties.

Before you do this, first enter command prompt, type in  **ipconfig /all** then press enter.Then record the ipv4 address and default gateway.

[image]

1. Open Network and Sharing Center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Right click on adapter and click on properties
4. Click on Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)
5. Choose use the following IP address
6. Type in IP address ,default gateway and DNS server you recorded in command prompt.
7. Click on OK, then the setting will be enabled.

Have a nice day,

Peter

Answer (score -1):

I have one more solution. We can give static IP address on every systems on the same subnet which router's DHCP provide to systems.